# Get notified on SMS delivery with SMS channel in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, sms-gateway, one-time-password

I am sending OTP SMS to the user through android app. For sending SMS I am using SMS channel. So I am just hitting URL to send SMS. I want my app to get notified when the SMS gets delivered to the user so that I can auto read that OTP.

Comment: This question is rather too brief for Stack Overflow, in my opinion - we normally like to see some research, or the start of some code. What do the Android docs say? (Also, please try to refrain from asking for urgency in your questions - people who help here are volunteers, and they will answer at their leisure).

Answer (score 0):

please see the code for reference-

```
main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send SMS" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

SMS1Activity.java

```
package selva.sms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SMS1Activity extends Activity 
{
Button btnSendSMS;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
sendSMS("5556", "Hi You got a message!");
}
});
}
//---sends an SMS message to another device---

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
new Intent(SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
//---when the SMS has been sent---
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
switch (getResultCode())
{
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
}
}, new IntentFilter(SENT));
//---when the SMS has been delivered---
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
switch (getResultCode())
{
case Activity.RESULT_OK:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
}
}, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
}
```

I copied this from [androidprogramz.blogspot](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/send-sms-and-receive-delivery-report-in.html)

Comment: as I said I am using sms channel not the sms manager. I just need to hit a single url to sms.